# Three.js doesn't show on mobile with specific imports

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a multi-page website using HTML, CSS, and THREE.js. I'm using three version 0.154.0 and cdn links inside my import statements in my three.js files.

The problem I'm facing is in my main.js file that is linked to my home html file. I'm importing Flow, FontLoader, and TextGeometry. Everything works just fine on all browsers on my laptop and desktop, but on mobile (iphone - safari & google, both the latest updates) my three.js scene isn't showing only for my main.js file - my aboutme.js scene shows just like it would on desktop.

In my **aboutme.js file** that is linked to my about me html file, my only import is three such as:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js';
```

and my scene loads just fine in both desktop and mobile on all browsers:
[image: about me three.js scene]

In my **main.js file**, here are my imports:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js';
import { Flow } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/modifiers/CurveModifier.js';
import { FontLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
```

and on desktop or laptop, my scene loads just fine:
[image: main.js scene]
**but doesn't show on mobile, while the aboutme.js file shows on all devices.**

When I delete the imports inside my main.js except for `import { THREE }`, and only have the morphing sphere and triangle meshs showing, it loads just fine on mobile. But when I add the other 3 imports, so I'm able to have the 3D text following a curve around the morphing sphere ([inspiration found at this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=curve#webgl_modifier_curve)) the scene, while working just fine on desktop and laptop, just simply doesn't show while on mobile.

In the link to the official three.js examples webpage above, the text following a curve works just fine on mobile, but not for me.

***Does anybody have an idea on why these imports in main.js are causing my scene to crash on mobile?***

Here is my **main.js file** which doesn't show the scene in mobile due to the imports:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js';
import { Flow } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/modifiers/CurveModifier.js';
import { FontLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';

const curveHandles = [];
let g, flow;
let t, v3 = new THREE.Vector3();


// config
    const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector(".diagram canvas"), antialias: true, alpha: true});          
    const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);          

    camera.position.x = 140;
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    // controls.enabled = true;

    const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 25, 600);
    light1.position.set(-600, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light1);

    const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 15, 175);
    light2.position.set(120, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light2);
//config


//sphere
    var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 128, 128);
    const sphere_material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
        color: 0x0000ff,
        metalness: 1,
        roughness: 0
    } );
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, sphere_material);

    scene.add(sphere);
    sphere.rotation.y = ( - Math.PI / 2 );
    sphere.position.set(0,0,0)
    sphere.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
    sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    var update = function() {

        var time = performance.now() * 0.003;
        const positions = sphere.geometry.attributes.position;
    
        for (var i = 0; i < positions.count; i++) {
    
            v3.fromBufferAttribute(positions, i).setLength(6);
    
            let n = noise.perlin3(v3.x + time * .1, v3.y + time * 0.03, v3.z + time * 0.03);
    
            v3.setLength(20 - 10 * n + 5);
    
            positions.setXYZ(i, v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
    
        }
    
        positions.needsUpdate = true;
        sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals(); 
    }
//sphere


//triangles
    const createTriangle = (x, y, z, rx, rz) => {
        const triangle_geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 160, 0, 3 );
        const triangle_material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
            color: 0x0000ff,
            emissive: 0x000000,
            metalness: 0.8,
            roughness: 1,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        } ); 

        const triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangle_geometry, triangle_material)

        triangle.position.set(x, y, z);
        triangle.rotateX(rx);
        triangle.rotateZ(rz);
        triangle.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
        triangle.name = 'tri';
        scene.add(triangle);
    }
    createTriangle(-200, 120, 240, 180, 0);
    createTriangle(-260, -120, -240, 60, 15);
    createTriangle(-110, 220, -140, 0, 0);
    createTriangle(-300, -120, 150, 150, -15);
//triangles


//curves and 3d text
    const initialPoints = [
        { x: 28, y: -5, z: -28 },
        { x: 28, y: -5, z: 28 },
        { x: -28, y: -5, z: 28 },
        { x: -28, y: -5, z: -28 },
    ];
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 );
    const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    for ( const handlePos of initialPoints ) {

        const handle = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, boxMaterial );
        handle.position.copy( handlePos );
        curveHandles.push( handle );
        scene.add( handle );

    }

    const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(
        curveHandles.map( ( handle ) => handle.position )
    );
    curve.curveType = 'centripetal';
    curve.closed = true;

    const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
    const line = new THREE.LineLoop(
        new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points ),
        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } )
    );

    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load( './../font/FONT.json', function ( font ) {

        const geometry = new TextGeometry( 'John Jacobs', {
            font: font,
            size: 10,
            height: 0.05,
            curveSegments: 12,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 0.02,
            bevelSize: 1,
            bevelOffset: 0,
            bevelSegments: 5,
        } );

        geometry.rotateX( Math.PI );
        geometry.rotateY( Math.PI );


        const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
            color: 0xffffff
        } );

        const objectToCurve = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )

        flow = new Flow( objectToCurve );
        flow.updateCurve( 0, curve );
        scene.add( flow.object3D );

    } );
//curves and 3d text

const dark_button = document.getElementById('mode1');
dark_button.addEventListener("click", darkMode);
function darkMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0c1424";
    sphere.material.color.setHex(0x0000ff);

    // Create a new material for the 3D text
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    });

    // Update the material of the objectToCurve mesh
    objectToCurve.material = newMaterial;
};

const light_button = document.getElementById('mode2');
light_button.addEventListener("click", lightMode);
function lightMode() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    document.body.style.color = "#000000";
    sphere.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);

    // Create a new material for the 3D text
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    });

    // Update the material of the objectToCurve mesh
    objectToCurve.material = newMaterial;
}

//top of page
    function moveCamera() {
        t = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        scene.traverse(function(node) {
            if(node.name == 'tri'){
                node.rotation.x = t*0.005;
            }
        });

        if ( flow ) {

            flow.moveAlongCurve( 0.0005 + (t * -0.00005));
    
        }

    }
    document.body.onscroll = moveCamera;
    moveCamera();
//top of page



//resize
    function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {

        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        const width = canvas.clientWidth;
        const height = canvas.clientHeight;

        if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
            renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }

    }
//resize


let oldx = 0;
let oldy = 0;
window.onmousemove = function(e){
    let changex = e.x - oldx
    let changey = e.y - oldy
    camera.position.x -= changex/50
    camera.position.y += changey/-50

    oldx = e.x
    oldy = e.y
}



//main function
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

    update();

    if ( flow ) {

        flow.moveAlongCurve( 0.001 );

    }

    sphere.rotation.y += 0.002;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

And here is my **aboutme.js file** that does work on mobile:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js';

let renderer, scene, camera;
let v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
let t, newT;

// config
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector(".diagram canvas"), antialias: true, alpha: true});                

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 25, -105 );
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    // controls.enabled = true;

    const light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 300 ); // soft white light
    scene.add( light );
    light.position.set( 20, -10, -20);


    //sphere
    var sphere_geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 55, 20, 100, 10, 2, 50); 
    const sphere_material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
        color: 0x0000ff,
        metalness: 1,
        roughness: 1,
        wireframe: false
    } );
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, sphere_material);

    scene.add(sphere);
    // sphere.rotation.y = (Math.PI / 2);
    sphere.position.set(0,0,0)
    sphere.scale.set(1, 1, 1)
    sphere.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    var update = function() {

        var time = performance.now() * 0.003;
        const positions = sphere.geometry.attributes.position;

        for (var i = 0; i < positions.count; i++) {

            v3.fromBufferAttribute(positions, i).setLength(10);

            let n = noise.perlin3(v3.x + time * .01, v3.y + time * 0.05, v3.z + time * 0.008);

            v3.setLength(20 - 20 * n + 5);

            positions.setXYZ(i, v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);

        }

        positions.needsUpdate = true;
        sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals(); 
    }



//resize
    function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {

        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        const width = canvas.clientWidth;
        const height = canvas.clientHeight;

        if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
            renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }

    }
//resize

//main function
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();

    update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

And here is my **home.html file** that links to my **main.js file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styling/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styling/index.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>John Jacobs</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- HTML -->


        <div class="menu" id="menu">
          <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="menu-btn_burger">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu-slider">

            <div class="theme-container">
                <!-- <a href="" onclick="myFunction()"><div class="mode" id="mode1"></div></a>
                <a href=""><div class="mode" id="mode2"></div></a> -->
                <div class="mode" id="mode1"></div><br>
                <div class="mode" id="mode2"></div>  
            </div>

            <div class="menu-items">
                <a id="menu-item-selected" href="index.html">Home</a><br><br>
                <a href="developer.html">Developer</a><br><br>
                <a href="designer.html">Designer</a><br><br>
                <a href="mailto:bryceccode@gmail.com">Experience</a><br><br>
                <a href="https://github.com/callahan-codes">Contact</a>
            </div>

        </div>



        </div> 

        <span class="diagram"><canvas></canvas></span>

        <main>
        
           <p>Home.html</p>

        </main>

        <div class="load-container">
            <div class="loader loader-black loader-5"></div>
        </div>



    <!-- HTML -->

    <!-- JS -->

      <!-- outer -->
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
      <script src="../script/particles.js"></script>
      <script src="../script/burger.js"></script>
      <script src="../script/load.js"></script>
      <script>AOS.init();</script>
      

      <!-- three -->
      <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
        }
      </script>
      <script src="https://fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/teaf/blob/v4/js/perlin.js"></script>
      <script type="module" src="../script/main.js"></script>


    <!-- JS -->

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I thought i should include it. You'll notice that in my home.html file, i'm using an importmap, which I also call exactly the same in my aboutme.html file:

```
      <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
        }
      </script>
      <script src="https://fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/teaf/blob/v4/js/perlin.js"></script>
      <script type="module" src="../script/main.js"></script>
```

Just to be clear, given the information above, a summery of above and my question is:

Having certain imports is causing my main.js file to not show only on mobile. My aboutme.js file, which is linked to my aboutme.html file, shows on all browsers and devices. My main.js file, works on all browsers on desktop but the scene doesn't show on mobile. When i remove the Flow, TextGeometry, and FontLoader imports, and only have the triangles and morphing sphere in my scene, it shows on all devices, including mobile, just like my aboutme.js file.

***Does anybody have an idea on why these imports in main.js are causing my scene to crash on mobile?***